# Can I transfer an app to somebody else without having them to pay for developer enrollment?

Tags: applications, app-store-connect, file-transfer

I am an app developer, and I have to transfer an app to a company, so the app won't have my name under the title in the AppStore. So it looks like they made it. My question is, do they have to pay for an enrollment, or can they just recieve the app for free, and if they can, how can they recieve it from me? I know you can transfer it from itunes connect, but it seems to me that you have to pay for an enrollment to get access to itunes connect.

Comment: app developer? iOS or Mac apps? Visit [this](https://developer.apple.com/). Look for Enterprise Distribution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the receiving company will need an [Apple Developer ID](https://developer.apple.com/membercenter/) and [membership of the Mac and/or iOS Developer Programs](https://developer.apple.com/programs/).

Part of the process of enrolling involves agreeing to Apple's terms of service and other legally binding agreements. Without agreeing to Apple's agreements, the receiving company will not be able to participate in Apple's App Store or Mac App Store.

It is possible to have applications associated with your Apple Developer ID but not participate in the App Stores. However, those applications will not be eligible for sale through Apple.